# SAS read a table from a SQL Server connection with name containing special characters

Tags: sql, sql-server, sas

I have a connection in SAS to a sql server table where the table name is 'Additions_to_Aggregate$'.  The quotes are part of the name.  So in my SAS editor when I try to run the below in part of my code, I'm returned errors because SAS is reading it as string rather than as the table name.

```
proc sql;
Create Table Name_Compare as
SELECT DISTINCT a.Insured_Name, agg.Policy_Holder_Name, a.Segment
FROM MySQLLib.ADV_Portfolio_Split as a
LEFT JOIN MySQLLib.'Additions_to_Aggregate$'n.data as agg 
on a.Insured_Name = agg.Policy_Holder_Name;
quit;
```

Is there any way to force SAS to read the table name as a literal string, or do you have any other solution ideas?  I already tried renaming the table in SAS explorer but I get this error and don't know how to interpret it.

[image: SAS Error Message]

Comment: @BeanFrog Assuming this is SAS syntax, that doesn't work in SAS as far as I'm aware, that is SQL Server syntax.

Comment: Just to clarify, Cole, you're not doing this in pass-through (`connect to sql... select * from connection to sql ( )`) but in SAS syntax environment using LIBNAME connection (`MySQL` is a libname to a sql database)?

Comment: @Joe Yes this is SAS syntax.  I edited my original post to show that.  Also, letting you know I posted a reply to your original solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for a name literal.  Either:

```
LEFT JOIN MySQL.'Additions_to_Aggregate$'n
```

or

```
LEFT JOIN MySQL."'Additions_to_Aggregate$'"n
```

depending on how SAS handles the quotes in the DBMS connection; it may or may not require the second, outside pair of quotes. If for some reason you need single quotes around it (SAS doesn't have any special meaning for single/double outside of macro resolution), you can double them up:

```
LEFT JOIN MySQL.'''Additions_to_Aggregate$'''n
```

Comment: I tried the first solution you wrote.  It does look like SAS now recognizes it as a data table, but it looks like it's reading the n as part of the table name.  SAS returns in the error: LEFT JOIN MySQLLib.'Additions_to_Aggregate$'n.data as agg

Comment: What is the rest of the error?  That's what I'd expect SAS to do.  It's possible the error is that the table doesn't exist (in which case the second/third case may be needed), but it could be something else, too?

Comment: This is the entire error

proc sql;
87   Create Table Name_Compare as
88   SELECT DISTINCT a.Insured_Name, agg.Policy_Holder_Name, a.Segment
89   FROM MySQLLib.ADV_Portfolio_Split as a
90   LEFT JOIN MySQLLib.'Additions_to_Aggregate$'n as agg
91   on a.Insured_Name = agg.Policy_Holder_Name;
ERROR: File MYSQLLIB.'Additions_to_Aggregate$'n.DATA does not exist.

Comment: Actually after looking into it, the second method you suggested works.  I was screwed up because I added the underscore characters instead of spaces.  Since it automatically added underscores to field names within my tables I assumed it would have done it to the table names as well.  Thank you for your help!